# Working of newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor, if thread already busy

Tags: java, android

My requirement is to make a service which keeps on checking a queue after specific interval & process the elements in queue.

For scheduling task after 10 seconds, I'm using:

```
ScheduledExecutorService schd = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
schd.scheduleAtFixedRate(readQueueRunnable, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My question is suppose first time, in queue there are many elements and my single thread starts processing the queue.

Even after 10 seconds my first thread is still executing it.

So when after 10 seconds, runnable is called again, will it stop the previous executing thread and start the new one.
Or, it will check if thread is already running & if it is running then it will skip going inside Runnable in  that case.

Comment: Scheduling queue checks sounds odd, I'd just use [BlockingQueue#poll(timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) in a dedicated consumer thread

Answer (score 19):

`newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();` creates an executor with a single thread that will never do anything in parallel to itself. A single thread can't execute more than 1 thing at a time.

If your task takes longer than the desired rate of 10 seconds, it will, upon completion put itself back into the task queue cleared for immediate execution because the target time is already in the past.

A task will not be executed earlier than specified but it can always execute later.

The executor will also try to catch up to the specified rate. If it needs to have executed the task at 10 seconds, 20 seconds and 30 seconds after calling `scheduleAtFixedRate` it will run them back to back if it was busy until then.

A repeating task that consistently takes longer than the desired rate will effectively slow down the rate and never catch up.

If your tasks on average take less then the rate you'll have exactly as many executions of the task as the rate dictates.

> So when after 10 seconds, runnable is called again, will it stop the previous executing thread and start the new one.

Executors re-use their thread(s) and they execute all `Runnable`s you give them in sequence inside their thread(s). Executors also will not attempt to stop or interrupt a running task just because it takes too long.

> Or, it will check if thread is already running & if it is running then it will skip going inside Runnable in that case.

No. You can calculate ahead of time when fixed rate task execution time is supposed to be and the executor will attempt to meet that goal. If a target time is already in the past it will simply run as soon as possible.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) explains it like

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

The "not concurrently" part is meant for executors that have multiple threads. Not relevant here since that can't happen.

---

If you want that there is always a 10 second delay *between* tasks, use `scheduleWithFixedDelay`

With `scheduleAtFixedRate` when some executions take longer than the period you can see back to back execution of delayed tasks which is often undesired.

Example: execution the first time takes 25 seconds, each subsequent execution only takes 1 second. You'll end up with:

- at 0s - 1st execution on time
- at 25s - 2nd meant to run at 10s
- at 26s - 3rd meant to run at 20s

  - (3 seconds pause)
- at 30s - 4th on time again

If you use `scheduleWithFixedDelay` and set the delay to 10s you would end up with

- at 0s - 1st for 25s

  - (10 seconds pause)
- at 35s - 2nd for 1s

  - (10 seconds pause)
- at 46s - 3rd for 1s

  - (10 seconds pause)
- at 57s - 4th for 1s

Comment: Can I provide 2 different runnables to same worker ?

Comment: @JaydevKalivarapu not sure how you mean that, but you can schedule as many different runnables as you want.

Comment: And if I wanted to avoid the memory leak by saying that between one operation and the other 10 seconds must elapse but if an operation lasts 30 seconds it is not put in reserve 3 times the waiting time?

Comment: I think the statement about a growing queue of tasks might be inaccurate. The docs does not say that it will schedule the tasks, it just says the task may start late. Also this question/answer points out the queue size does not grow when task is taking longer than the execution time, i've tried this as well and the queue does not grow.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529273

Comment: @YunusCanEmre Hmm, good point. It's not wrong if you add a new task every 10 seconds by repeatedly calling one of the `schedule` methods. I either didn't know or was thinking of that. Work queues will overflow if you produce work faster than the queue is emptied, just not by a single task that repeats itself every time it finishes

Comment: @YunusCanEmre I've updated the answer. For reference, https://gist.github.com/zapl/589ead8e74c3deda2fdfee46313d0126 is the old version.