# Should single thread scheduled executor be used to schedule two tasks with different delays?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

In a Java program I call `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();` to create an executor that I subsequently use to schedule two tasks. These tasks have different fixed delays, something like this:

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task1, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task2, 0, 100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I tested this portion of program with smaller delays and it worked as expected. In production, however, it stops sometimes after a day, sometimes after a week or so without logging any exceptions. To be on the safe side and following the advice given in related questions I enclosed both tasks in

```
try {
    doStuff();
} catch (Throwable th) {
    logStuff();
}
```

The problem remained and I checked if logging was configured correctly. It was.

In the documentation of `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` method it is mentioned that

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute
>         sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any
>         given time.

This suits me and I don't understand why the program exits without any visible problems.

Is this type of executor suitable for the mentioned scenario? Are there any pitfalls? What may go wrong and remain unnoticed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436761/working-of-newsinglethreadscheduledexecutor-if-thread-already-busy

Comment: The likeliest reason is that `doStuff` gets stuck... You can maybe add a logging entry `before doStuff` and `after doStuff` in your try block to verify that hypothesis.

Comment: A "single thread executor" is just a thread pool executor with `maxThreads = minThreads = 1` and the task queue is a `linkedBlockingQueue`. What this means is that when a task finishes it puts itself on the queue for its next execution, along with the timestamp at which it must execute. As such, if you can take a heap and thread dump of the process when it's stuck, then you can look into your executor for (a) the work queue (it should have a task scheduled in the past, but not yet run) and (b) in the thread dump look at `runWorker` and whether it has a stuck task preventing anything else.