# Why is the queue size of a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor always 0?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I’m using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to schedule a task every millisecond. As far as I understand, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` uses an unbounded queue internally and appends tasks when none of the threads is available to execute it.

As a result I would have assumed the following: if I have an executor with a single thread and the task that is periodically run takes longer than the frequency with which it is scheduled then the queue size increases continuously. Somehow this does not seem to be correct though for my following minimal code example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, TimeUnit}

object MinimalExample {

  val numberOfThreads = 1
  val executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(numberOfThreads)

  def execute(): Unit = {
    val thread = new TestThread(executor)
    val initialDelay = 0
    val interval = 1
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread, initialDelay, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    execute()
  }
}

class TestThread(executor: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) extends Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("just slept 2 seconds")
    println(s"queue size: ${executor.getQueue().size()}")
  }
}
```

It always prints 0 for the size of the queue. How is that possible if the task takes more than 2 seconds and is scheduled every millisecond? Am I missing something?

Comment: While the task is executing, it's not in the queue.

Comment: why are you creating a thread pool with only 1 thread? defeating the entire purpose of a thread pool

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz It does not make a difference whether I use 1 or 10 threads. The result is the same.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, the task currently run is not in the queue. But I would have expected a new task to be added every millisecond?

Comment: This is kind of explained in the Javadoc: _If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute._ Reading into that, you can assume the next execution of a task isn't scheduled until the current one completes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis When I read the Javadoc, I understood that a new task instance would be submitted to the queue but not executed until the previous task instance was finished. By getting the queue size I tried to figure out if my task really could be scheduled with the configured interval or if the task instances piled up.
But I suppose that was wrong and the task is not even submitted to the queue in that case.

Comment: Put a longer initial delay and query the queue size right after the call to `scheduleAtFixedRate`. It will return 1. Work out the _period_ to execute once, then query the queue size again. It will return 1, since the task was readded for its next scheduled time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a periodic task is being executed, it is removed (`take()`-n or `poll()`-ed) from the internal queue. It is re-added later when the task is successfully finished. (Or not if it throws an exception.) This applies to both `scheduleWithFixedDelay` and `scheduleAtFixedRate`. `getQueue` returns the internal queue of tasks *waiting* for execution. This queue also contains delayed tasks that are waiting for their delay to expire, but not tasks that are currently being executed. (Use `getActiveCount` to query that.)

Quoting the javadoc for `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start *late*, but will **not** concurrently execute.

This is done by re-adding the periodic task to the queue only after it's execution. The task itself is not present in the queue during it's execution and will never be present in it multiple times.